# Superposition of waves with different initial phase in Quantum Mechanics

Tags: quantum-mechanics, fourier-transform, superposition

In Quantum Mechanics, if a particle's state is a superposition of *many* states, then we say that its position is well-defined (by the Heisenberg uncertainty principle, because here we have ill-defined momentum). In the addition of each wave of momentum $p$ using Fourier series, where do we involve the initial phase of each wave that we are adding?
For example, say we add those two waves and get the function that I aforementioned. But if we add up those waves with only one of them having an initial phase of $\pi/12$ (making it  $\exp[i(k x + \pi/12)]$ ), won't we get a function different from the one from the first addition? So we still add up the same states of definite momentum but get a different function.

Is there something wrong with my reasoning? Where do we involve the phase of each added wave(I believe it is something in complex analysis which I don't know about)? As someone stated at the comments, this at heart is a Fourier series question, so some mathematics indicating where the phase comes into play in Fourier series would be much appreciated.

NOTE: this question was edited so as to delete some things that I wrote which where wrong, so you might see some answers that try to explain something that might now be missing from the question but was present before.

Comment: What do you mean "you get the delta function somewhere else"? The phase of $\mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i}\pi}$ just stays in front of it, as far as I can see.

Comment: I edited. Its not the π that matters, but the fact that there is initial phase in the play

Comment: Now the phase of $\mathrm{e}^{\pi\mathrm{i}/12}$ will just be in front of the delta function. You haven't changed anything. Please show explicitly how you think the "delta function will be located somewhere else".

Comment: What do you mean with "that phase will be in front of the delta function"?

Comment: Like, uh, $\mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i}\pi}\delta(x)$?

Comment: I will give you another scenario. Let's say we add two waves of momentum P1 and P2. We add P1 wave with no initial phase and P2 with initial phase of π/12. Won't that give a resulting superimposed function that is different from the function that we would have got if we added both those waves without any of them having initial phase?

Comment: @ACuriousMind so adding waves with initial phase will just  multiply the delta function?

Comment: Ah, if the have *different* phases, it will influence the result (you won't get a delta function). If it's an overall phase, it's just in front. Please show a bit more of your explicit thoughts in the question, I still don't know what your exact question is.

Comment: I will change it in a bit. So, for adding via Fourier series, where does the phase of each wave that will be added comes in? Say the series will just be Ψ=C1sin(2x) + C2sin(3x). If I want to add the second wave with initial phase how will I do it? The only thing that proffessors teach is how to find the coefficients Cn and the momentums, but they never mention how to find out if any of those waves must be added with initial phase.

Comment: It really looks like you need to write a complete computation yourself. You're just forgetting about the phase factors multiplying the delta functions, as already mentioned by @ACuriousMind.

Comment: By the way, this isn't a quantum mechanics question at heart. It's really just understanding Fourier series.

Comment: @DanielSank yes it is. I posted another question that had to do only with Fourier series but no answer or comment was provided. So I changed it as a quantum mechanical problem

Comment: Guys, sorry for the confusion and misunderstanding. Using the delta function was just an example. I changed the question in order to be more clear and easy to read. I just don't understand where does the phase of the waves that we are adding come into play, as in the Fourier series it seems(from basic first-course Quantum mechanics) that we just add waves of different wavelengths(momentum)

Comment: By the way, the first sentence of the question makes a statement which is incorrect. Adding many momentum eigenstates does not necessarily give a state whose wave function is sharp in $x$ space.

Comment: Forgive me as I am only an amateur in QM. But isn't that what the Heisenberg Uncertainty Principle states?

Comment: If you insist on using trig functions for your Fourier series, you can add a phase by using a sine and cosine of the same frequency. For example, sin(x) + cos(x) is proportional to sin(x + pi/4).

Comment: I believe the other comments are misunderstanding you because you asked the question in the context of QM, where it's more practical to use the complex version of the Fourier transform, Ce^(ikx). In this case C is complex so the phase is just in there, it multiplies.

Comment: @KevinZhou thank you, an answer has also said to me this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some correct things and some incorrect things in your question. But let me just give the main points.

First of all, if you add two states together with different relative phases, you get different states. For instance,

$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}|\psi_1\rangle + \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}|\psi_2\rangle$$

is a different quantum-mechanical state than

$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}|\psi_1\rangle + e^{i\pi/12}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}|\psi_2\rangle.$$

There are in fact a (continually) infinite number of different states that you can make out of $|\psi_1\rangle$ and $|\psi_2\rangle$,

$$\cos\theta|\psi_1\rangle + e^{i\phi}\sin\theta|\psi_2\rangle,$$

parameterized by the quantities $\theta$ and $\phi$.

For concreteness, and directly related to your question, if we work in the position representation, you can form the equal-amplitudes superposition of plane-wave states and make a delta-function, which can be thought of as a state of well-defined position (although such states do not actually physically exist). One possibility is

$$\delta(x) = \int\frac{dk}{2\pi}e^{ikx}$$

(In the abstract ket-space of position eigenvectors $|x\rangle$, this state would be the state $|0\rangle$.)

However, if you add a relative phase $e^{-ikx_0}$ to each plane-wave, then this becomes

$$\delta(x-x_0) = \int\frac{dk}{2\pi}e^{ikx}e^{-ikx_0},~~~~~~(1)$$

which in the abstract ket space is $|x_0\rangle$. To see this maybe a little more clearly, we can re-write the previous equations in the abstract ket space completely:

$$|0\rangle = \int{dk}|k\rangle.$$
$$|x_0\rangle = \int{dk}e^{-ikx_0}|k\rangle.~~~~~~(2)$$

In other words, we are adding up the momentum states $|k\rangle$ with different relative phases, so we get different states.

Most simply, if you add two plane waves with different relative phases, you obviously get different functions:

$$e^{ikx}+e^{-ikx}=2\cos{kx}$$

but

$$e^{ikx}+e^{i\pi}e^{-ikx}=2i\sin{kx}$$

### Cleaning up some misconceptions

> In Quantum Mechanics, if a particle's state is a superposition of many states of definite momentum, then we say that it's position is well-defined

This is not in general true. We say that the "position is well-defined" only if the superposition of momentum states is of a particular form (see equations (1) and (2) above). And it is always necessary to add this caveat: there really is no such thing as a state of well-defined position; it a mathematical convenience that, if used carefully, can be used as an *approximation* of a narrow wave-packet.

> So say we add up two states of definite momentum (sine functions) so we get a function in position space.

This might just be an imprecise statement, but it's important to understand that a state is an abstract quantity that can be *represented* in either the position or momentum representation. The states of definite momentum are the eigenstates of the momentum operator, and when written in the position representation (i.e. as functions of $x$) take the form of plane waves:

$$|k\rangle = \int dx \langle x|\psi_k\rangle |x\rangle,\\
\langle x|\psi_k\rangle=\psi_k(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{ikx}.$$

If you add up two momentum eigenstates, you can represent this function in position space, or you can represent this function in momentum space.

> For example, say we add those two waves and get the function that I aforementioned. But if we add up those waves with only one of them having an initial phase of $\pi/12$ (making it $\exp[i(kx+\pi/12)]$), won't we get a function different from the one from the first addition?

Yep. See above.

> So we still add up the same states of definite momentum but get a different function.

Yep! Nothing to see here really. I feel like this is the crux of the problem, but I can't tell what it is you're actually confused about.

> ...so some mathematics indicating where the phase comes into play in Fourier series would be much appreciated.

Under suitable niceness conditions of the functions, suitable boundary conditions etc., a complex-valued function $f(x)$ can be expanded in a Fourier series as

$$f(x) = \sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} A_n e^{i2\pi nx},$$

where the $A_n$'s are in general *complex*, so they can be represented in polar form as $re^{i\phi}$. And the point is, if you change those phases $e^{i\phi}$, you get out a different function $f$. That's it.

### Final note

An *overall* complex phase is irrelevant. That is, $|\psi\rangle$ is the same state as $e^{i\phi}|\psi\rangle$, but as soon as you are forming superpositions, then the *relative* phases matter, as I've discussed.

Comment: About the Fourier series: so I add each wave and give it an amplitude of r and initial phase exp[iφ]? If so, how can I calculate r and exp[iφ] from An(assume that I already found An)?

Comment: "you can form the equal-amplitudes superposition of plane-wave states". Why can I create a superposition that is restricted to summing up waves that have equal amplitudes? Isn't that way too restrictive? Shouldn't each wave has its own initial phase and amplitude?

Comment: "You *can* form the..." (emphasis added). The point is that *if* you form the equal-amplitudes, equal-relative-phases linear combination over all plane-waves, you get delta functions. If your form some other linear combinations, you get some other states. As for your first question, that is a basic property of complex numbers, and if you are studying Fourier analysis and quantum mechanics, you definitely need to have a basic working knowledge of complex numbers! It's even important in engineering, so that's definitely something to study!

Comment: I am starting my physics major in a few days, and I am starting with a waves course and a complex analysis course so I can move on to quantum mechanics! Anyways, thank you for the answer!