# Periodicity of function as a result of superposition in Quantum Mechanics

Tags: quantum-mechanics, superposition

Say we add infinitely many waves (states of definite momentum) so as to produce a function that gives a very well-defined position, does that addition(using Fourier series) make that function periodic? I mean, if the added waves are themselves periodic(in Fourier they are harmonic), does that mean that the resulting function will also be periodic?
If so, in the case of the superposition of states that give us a Dirac Delta function, does that mean that the delta function will reappear after some long distance or is it just a single spike in all space?

Comment: What is the periodicity of the sum of two sine functions with frequencies that have an irrational ratio?

Comment: Don't know what you mean, really! I am just starting to get into these things.

Comment: My point is to think through the simplest possible case first. What does it mean for the resulting function to be periodic? How can you *show* that the sum of two sine functions is periodic? Here's another way to do things: what is the condition on the frequencies of two sine functions that would make the sum of the two sine functions periodic?

Comment: A Dirac delta function is a mathematical abstraction (a limit of a smooth function). There is no physical object with that distribution.

Comment: @CuriousOne the delta function in my question is just an example. It could be any function.

Comment: @march I know that a function to be periodic means that it repeats itself after some time/distance. I do not know about the condition of the frequencies.

Comment: I'm not asking to see if you know the answer. I'm asking to try to get *you* to figure out the answer. You should try to work it out. Write down the math, or plot the function with Mathematica or a graphing calculator. Don't just try to think about it!

Comment: @march the only thing that I can think of is this: if the frequencies' ratio is rational then the resulting function will be periodic while if its irrational then the resulting function will not be periodic. Am I right? If so, because in order to produce a delta function you must add MANY waves of different frequencies that not all have rational ratio then the delta function will not repeat itself. But if we are using discrete Fourier series(only some waves) then we could add waves whose frequencies all have rational ratios between them, so the resulting function will repeat itself.Am I right?

Comment: Just wanted to make sure that you know that delta functions are NOT real physical solutions. They are  very convenient mathematical tools, though. The physical approach to localized wave functions would be Gaussian wave packets which have the nice properties that they satisfy the uncertainty relation precisely and their Fourier transform is also a Gaussian.

Comment: yes @CuriousOne I know that! Thank you for the clarification though

Comment: I see what you mean. Google "Dirac comb": it is a periodic array of delta functions, and it can be written as a Fourier series with *constant* coefficients.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd like to pick apart a few things. First, I'll echo `CuriousOne`s comment that a state of well-defined position, represented in position space as delta function $\delta (x-x_0)$ and in momentum space as a plane-wave, is not a true physically realizable state. It is at least a nice mathematical device, however, and we can roughly think of it as an approximation for a very narrow wave-packet.

That important caveat out of the way, let's work in the position basis spanned by the states $|{x}\rangle$, where

$$\langle x'| x\rangle = \delta(x-x').$$

This delta function can be written as the Fourier transform of plane-wave via

$$\psi(x) = \delta(x-x_0) = \int \frac{dk}{{2\pi}}e^{-i k x}e^{i k x_0},$$

so we can think of this "state" as being a linear superposition of all the plane-wave states $e^{-ikx}$ with equal probabilities (but varying phases given by $e^{i k x_0}$. From a Fourier analysis perspective, we can think of this as a superposition of oscillatory functions of wavelength $\lambda = 2\pi/k$. Since $k$ can be any real number, $k$ can be any real number, and so in this expansion there exist wavelengths that are irrational multiples of each other, making it so that this function is not periodic.

#### A quick aside

If you add two sine functions

$$f(x) = \sin(k_1 x) + \sin(k_2 x)$$,

then the resulting function is periodic if and only if the $k$'s form a rational ratio. To see this, note that in order for this function to be periodic, both sine functions must go through an integer multiple of cycles in the same $\Delta x$.

Extending this idea, in order for an arbitrary sum of oscillatory functions to be a periodic function, there must be some minimum $k$ that all the individual $k$'s are multiples of.

#### Thus

If you form an equal superposition of plane waves in the form of a Fourier *series*, rather than a Fourier *transform* as above, you get a periodic function. That is,

$$\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} e^{i2\pi x/\lambda_0} = \sum_{m=-\infty}^{\infty}\delta(x-m\lambda_0),$$

where $\lambda_0$ is the minimum wavelength of the plane-waves that show up and hence *is* the wavelength of the resulting function. The resulting "function" is known as a Dirac comb and consists of an infinite array of equally spaced delta functions.

The Dirac comb is actually used in physics: it shows up in simple models for solids displaying a band structure, and it shows up in the description of the [frequency comb](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frequency_comb), for which John Hall of CU Boulder and NIST won a Nobel prize.

Comment: as it seems you know about Fourier series and transforms, there is a question that I am much interested in an answer by you in this link http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/204044/superposition-of-waves-with-different-initial-phase-in-quantum-mechanics/204086?noredirect=1#comment435612_204086